# cumulative incidence plot in R: function cuminc and the arguments 'rho'

Tags: r, survival-analysis, risk-analysis

I have made a cumulative incidence plot using cmprsk::cuminc and then ggcompetingrisks for plotting. I have a questions relates to cuminc and the arguments 'rho' (power of the weight function used in the tests). Is the default value '0' always the best choice?

Code snippet:

```
cif <- cuminc(ftime   = bwtab$fachsem,
          fstatus = bwtab$status,
          group   = bwtab$studgang,
          rho     = 0,
          cencode = 0)
```

Comment: hi Steve. This question *might* be better asked at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) the statistics forum of SO.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know Cross Validated. I will ask the question there.

Comment: Hi anyone has the link of the post in Cross Validated? I have the same question.